# How can I submit each row data into Asp .Net Controller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, ajax

[View Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVAP6.png)

I'm going to make an ERP Solutions for Educational Institute. Here, when the Student marks entry part comes, I became stuck, because I want to submit each student's data and work on it. I can't use **form tag** for each **tr**. Is there any way to submit row by onclick ? below Image will describe more. These columns can be dynamic, can be more **Written,Mcq,Attendance**

```
<table>
    <form method="POST" action="whatever">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="whatever">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
```

But apparently I cannot arrange the tags in that way .

Any good way to do this?

Comment: why not toss up a datagrid. They can then edit all values and tab around - almost like a spread sheet - then have just one save button for all the edits? It also less code for you to write, and using a grid view - or even a listview means the multiple rows of data is generated automatic for you - you don't have to nor want to write such markup by hand when you have all of these fantastic data-bound controls like gridview, listview or even the repeater control. Use the built in tools to do all the heavy lifting and dirty work for you.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal for your suggestions. I didn't think about gridview, listview. I just google it and get some info as you said. Any way I'll convert my this task with gridview.

Comment: yes, if you use a datagrid, listview or repeater? I suggest that you ALSO persist the data table - then  you can pull the repeater/grid back to the table, and then with one operation write the data table back to the database. The result is you write very little code, and can send + update ALL of the edits to the repeater in one shot. Here is a recent example I posted of how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617710/how-to-save-more-that-one-row-of-text-to-database-by-adding-input-fields-dynamic/66642733#66642733

Comment: and here is a repeater example - again same idea - one simple bit of code saves ALL data edits back to the table -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009811/creating-dynamic-id-for-textbox-in-repeater/67014268#67014268